# C++ calling a parent class function that uses an overriden function

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I was wondering if it is possible in C++ to call a parent class method that uses an overridden method without using the parent version of the overridden method. (I know this is unclear so I made an example!)

For example, below I would like to call class A's version of findPath() from an object of class B, while using the addPoint method that is defined by class B. Currently, if I call findPath() from an object of class B, it uses the addPoint method defined in class A.

Actual Output:

A.findPath(), path  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

B.findPath(), path = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Desired Output:

A.findPath(), path = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

B.findPath(), path = {2,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100}

```
class A 
{ 
public:
    vector<int> path;

    void addPoint(int num) {
        path.push_back(num);
    }

    vector<int> findPath() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addPoint(i);
        }
    } 
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void addPoint(int num) {
        path.push_back(num*num);
    }
};
```

At the moment, I am copying and pasting findPath into class B to get the desired output, but I feel like there should be an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: Note: there is no `overriden` function in example shown, due to no function being `virtual`.

Comment: If you call addPoint() from an expression with type B you will call B::addPoint(). But your classes are not polymorphic and addPoint() is not virtual, so if you call addPoint() through *a pointer to A* you'll call A::addPoint() even if the object pointed to is actually a B. As always, it would help if you provided a complete example, including the calls (i.e. a minimal main()), so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: So, would you mind providing an example of how you call the function, or are you not interested in good answers?

Comment: Not related to your question, but your code will not compile, because you forgot to add parenthesis to `findPath()`. Also, `findPath()` has a return value, so you should add `return path;` at the end of this function as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `virtual` in the base class. You should also add `override` in the derived class, compare the [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-override).

```
class A 
{ 
public:
    ...

    virtual void addPoint(int num) {
        path.push_back(num);
    }

    ...
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void addPoint(int num) override {
        path.push_back(num*num);
    }
};
```

Comment: `override` is optional and does not change the semantics (but instead indicates that we intended to do what we are doing), right?

Comment: That would change the semantics of older C++ programs. Can you quote a rule for that? I think a missing `override` still leaves the function virtual (i.e. doesn't change a thing in the produced code) but prompts a compiler warning. Funny enough, searching for the keyword in the 2012 standard did not result in a rule about that; it is mentioned in table 3 (2.11) as an "identifier with a special meaning"; but they don't elaborate what that meaning may be ;-). Oh, it's not a *key*word at all to begin with.

Comment: @WernerHenze That is not the case. The function is virtual if it was declared `virtual` in the base class. It makes no difference what the derived class annotates the function with, so long as the signatures match. `override` and `final` are just to get the compiler to check that the signatures do match and that a `virtual` function exists in the base class. And the `virtual` only really matters in the base; if the signatures match in the derived class, it adds nothing there (but if they mismatched by accident, you'd now be creating a new 'chain' of `virtual` functions starting in the derived)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica and @underscore_d You are right, there is no need to write `override`. My first answer was nonsense. I updated my answer post to reflect what is necessary and what is optional (but good style).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. This is known as the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). The name is a bit unfortunate, because it has nothing to do with C++ templates. A base class can implement something and derived classes only override the individual steps of the bigger "something".

For example:

```
struct Base {
     virtual void stepA() = 0;
     virtual void stepB() = 0;
     virtual void stepC() = 0;
     void do_something_complicated() {
          stepA();
          stepB();
          stepC();
     }
};
```

Derived classes only override the methods for the individual steps, while they are composed in the base class already.

In your example you forgot to declare `addPoint` as virtual, `A` should have a virtual destructor and using `override` is recommended to let the compiler help you in case of mistakes:

```
class A 
{ 
public:
    vector<int> path;

    virtual void addPoint(int num) {
        path.push_back(num);
    }

    vector<int> findPath() {                // () was missing
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            addPoint(i);
        }
        return path;                        // return was missing
    } 

    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void addPoint(int num) override {
        path.push_back(num*num);
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be a nice answer if you fix the compilation issues: add parenthesis to `findPath()` and some return value, most probably `return path;` at the end.
Also, you could use `virtual ~A() = default` to make use of other great language features.